# Correlation between assets used for valuing multi-asset options (Rainbow options, basket options etc.)

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, correlation

Is there an equivalent to implied volatility used when it comes to modelling correlation in option valuation for multi asset options such as rainbow options (best-of/worst-of calls/put), or is the best you can do to model the real world sample correlation of the time-series of the assets (or something other that I'm not considering)? Is there an industry standard to this?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a *sketch* of how one can model multiple underlyings that are correlated together, in order to then price some options on them (i.e. spread options). I welcome any remarks that might improve this sketch (either feel free to comment or edit my post).

Suppose you have a multifactor model, with two assets, $X_1$ and $X_2$. Suppose the two assets follow GBM, where $W_1$ and $W_1$ are *independent*, as follows:

$$dX_1(t)=X_1(t)\mu_1 dt+X_1(t)\sigma_1 \lambda_{1,1} dW_1(t)+X_1(t)\sigma_1 \lambda_{1,2} dW_2(t)$$

$$dX_2(t)=X_2(t)\mu_2 dt+X_2(t)\sigma_2 \lambda_{2,1} dW_2(t)+X_2(t)\sigma_2 \lambda_{2,2} dW_2(t)$$

Above, $\lambda_{i,j}$ is the loading onto each Brownian motion (i.e. the source of risk). By Ito's lemma applied to $ln(X_1)$ and $ln(X_2)$, we then have:

$$dln(X_1)=\left(\mu_1-0.5\sigma_1^2(\lambda_{1,1}^2+\lambda_{2,1}^2)\right)dt+\sigma_1 \lambda_{1,1} dW_1(t)+\sigma_1 \lambda_{1,2} dW_2(t)$$

And

$$dln(X_2)=\left(\mu_2-0.5\sigma_2^2(\lambda_{2,1}^2+\lambda_{2,2}^2)\right)dt+\sigma_2 \lambda_{2,1} dW_2(t)+\sigma_2 \lambda_{2,2} dW_2(t)$$

The two assets would then be correlated as follows:

$$Cov(X_1,X_2)=\mathbb{E}\left[X_1X_2\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]\mathbb{E}\left[X_2\right]=f\left(\lambda_{1,1},\lambda_{1,2},\lambda_{2,1},\lambda_{2,2}\right)$$

I.e. the covariance is a function of the $\lambda$ parameters (with the $\sigma$ being calibrated separately to liquid option prices).

The correlation is then simply $Corr=\frac{Cov(X_1,X_2}{Var(X_1)^{0.5}Var(X_2)^{0.5}}$ (again, the Corr being a function of the $\lambda$ parameters).

So when valuing a multi-asset option, each underlying will typically have it's own volatility $\sigma_i$, which doesn't need to be constant: can be a deterministic function of $t$ or even a stochastic vol. The tricky part is then to use liquid options on the individual underlyings to calibrate each of the $\sigma_i$ so that the model above prices liquid options correctly.

The correlation can be even trickier: either a historical correlation can be computed and one can attempt to chose the parameters $\lambda_{i,j}$ so that the historical *corr*  is equal the *Corr* quantity in the model above. Or (I have never seen this done, but apparently it's possible) one can try to extract the implied *corr* from liquid spread options.

Once the model is properly calibrated, it is then no issue to run a Monte-Carlo to price some payoff along the lines of $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\left(X_1(t)-X_2(t)\right)^+\right]$.